# how to append timestamp to file name for java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern

Tags: java, timestamp, filenames, java.util.logging

Hi I was wondering if anyone knows a way to append a timestamp to the log file name specified through logging.properties java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern

seems like something pretty straight forward but I cant seem to find a solution to this anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use log4j?

Answer (score 4):

I am afraid that just by configuration you can't set the file name in teh way you want.

Have a look at the code in `FileHandler.generate()` to convince you.

What you can do is write your own FileHandler that will handle this naming or switch to another log framework.

If you use java.util.logging, I wrote some years ago a [Formatter & a Handler](http://www.jroller.com/page/mcfoggy/?anchor=java_util_logging_%C3%A0_la) that can still be usefull, feel free to use.

Answer (score 1):

You could instantiate the `FileHandler` in code with pattern, limit, count etc parameters.
So, the pattern string can be formed consisting of date and time.

Example Code:

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat().format( new Date() );
FileHandler fh = new FileHandler( "./jay_log_%u.%g_" + timeStamp + ".log", 30000, 4);
logger.addHandler(fh);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use SLF4J which points again back to java.util.logging packages which seems to have this feature 
http://javablog.co.uk/2008/07/12/logging-with-javautillogging/

alternatively for a no-third-party-frameworks approach you can use a CustomFormatter a sample of which is already available here,
http://www.kodejava.org/examples/458.html